# options.time is not a number. (val=undefined) discord-giveaways

Tags: javascript, discord, bots, discord.js

I am making a giveaway command and got this error

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: options.time is not a number. (val=undefined)
```

Whenever I do !create 30s 1 nitro. I also tried !create 1 30s nitro but it keeps getting the same error everytime and I don't know have a clue how to fix it

Here is my code:

```
const { GiveawaysManager } = require("discord-giveaways");
const manager = new GiveawaysManager(bot, {
    storage: "./giveaways.json",
    updateCountdownEvery: 10000,
    default: {
        botsCanWin: false,
        embedColor: "#FF0000",
        reaction: ""
    }
})

bot.giveawaysManager = manager;

});
bot.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'create':
           bot.giveawaysManager.start(message.channel, {
                time: ms(args[0]),
                prize: args.slice(2).join(" "),
                winnerCount: parseInt(args[1]),

            });
            break;
```

Please help me thanks

Comment: Wouldnt you want `args[1]` instead of `args[0]`

Comment: Right now you are trying to do `ms(!create)` which ofcourse is not a number.

Comment: Thanks I did args[1] now it works @Elitezen